# Getting around the deprecation of java.net.URL

Tags: java

I'm migrating my code to Java 20.

In this release, the [java.net.URL#URL(java.lang.String)](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html#constructor-deprecation) got deprecated. Unfortunately, I have a class where I found no replacement for the old URL constructor.

```
package com.github.bottomlessarchive.loa.url.service.encoder;

import io.mola.galimatias.GalimatiasParseException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Optional;

/**
 * This service is responsible for encoding existing {@link URL} instances to valid
 * <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier">resource identifiers</a>.
 */
@Service
public class UrlEncoder {

    /**
     * Encodes the provided URL to a valid
     * <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier">resource identifier</a> and return
     * the new identifier as a URL.
     *
     * @param link the url to encode
     * @return the encoded url
     */
    public Optional<URL> encode(final String link) {
        try {
            final URL url = new URL(link);

            // We need to further validate the URL because the java.net.URL's validation is inadequate.
            validateUrl(url);

            return Optional.of(encodeUrl(url));
        } catch (GalimatiasParseException | MalformedURLException | URISyntaxException e) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    private void validateUrl(final URL url) throws URISyntaxException {
        // This will trigger an URISyntaxException. It is needed because the constructor of java.net.URL doesn't always validate the
        // passed url correctly.
        new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
    }

    private URL encodeUrl(final URL url) throws GalimatiasParseException, MalformedURLException {
        return io.mola.galimatias.URL.parse(url.toString()).toJavaURL();
    }
}
```

Luckily, I have tests for the class as well:

```
package com.github.bottomlessarchive.loa.url.service.encoder;

import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvSource;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Optional;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

class UrlEncoderTest {

    private final UrlEncoder underTest = new UrlEncoder();

    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource(
            value = {
                    "http://www.example.com/?test=Hello world,http://www.example.com/?test=Hello%20world",
                    "http://www.example.com/?test=ŐÚőúŰÜűü,http://www.example.com/?test=%C5%90%C3%9A%C5%91%C3%BA%C5%B0%C3%9C%C5%B1%C3%BC",
                    "http://www.example.com/?test=random word £500 bank $,"
                            + "http://www.example.com/?test=random%20word%20%C2%A3500%20bank%20$",
                    "http://www.aquincum.hu/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Aquincumi-F%C3%BCzetek_14_2008.pdf,"
                            + "http://www.aquincum.hu/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Aquincumi-F%C3%BCzetek_14_2008.pdf",
                    "http://www.aquincum.hu/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Aquincumi-F%C3%BCzetek_14 _2008.pdf,"
                            + "http://www.aquincum.hu/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Aquincumi-F%C3%BCzetek_14%20_2008.pdf"
            }
    )
    void testEncodeWhenUsingValidUrls(final String urlToEncode, final String expected) throws MalformedURLException {
        final Optional<URL> result = underTest.encode(urlToEncode);

        assertThat(result)
                .contains(new URL(expected));
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @CsvSource(
            value = {
                    "http://промкаталог.рф/PublicDocuments/05-0211-00.pdf"
            }
    )
    void testEncodeWhenUsingInvalidUrls(final String urlToEncode) {
        final Optional<URL> result = underTest.encode(urlToEncode);

        assertThat(result)
                .isEmpty();
    }
}
```

The only dependency it uses is the [galamatias](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.mola.galimatias/galimatias/0.2.1) URL library.

Does anyone have any ideas on how could I remove the `new URL(link)` code fragment while keeping the functionality the same?

I tried various things, like using `java.net.URI#create` but it did not produce the exact result as the previous solution. For example, URLs that contain non-encoded characters like a space in `http://www.example.com/?test=Hello world` resulted in an IllegalArgumentException. This was parsed by the URL class without giving an error (and my data contains a lot of these). Also, links that failed the URL conversion like `http://промкаталог.рф/PublicDocuments/05-0211-00.pdf` are converted to URI successfully with URI.create.

Comment: @Hulk URLs that contain non-encoded characters like a space in "http://www.example.com/?test=Hello world". This was parsed by the URL class without giving an error (and my data contains a lot of these). Also, links that failed the URL conversion like "http://промкаталог.рф/PublicDocuments/05-0211-00.pdf" are converted to URI successfully with URI.create.

Comment: You are right. I updated my question.

Comment: How was the space encoded in the old method? I have sometimes seen %20 for a space in a URL. You could add that substitution yourself. Are there some parameters you need to set in the new method to cover more characters?

Comment: @rossum As seen in the test class. Some of them are already properly URL encoded, while others are not. :/ The URL's construction did not validate against URL encoding. Then the URI was created like this for further validation: `new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The problem

The main problem seems to be that the `UrlEncoder` service is dealing with a mix of encoded, unencoded and partially encoded URLs. More than that, there isn't a good way to to know which one is which.

This leads to ambiguity because certain characters can have different meanings when encoded vs unencoded. For instance, given a partially encoded URLs it isn't trivial to tell if a character such as `'&'` is part of a query parameter (and thus should be encoded) or acting as a separator (and thus shouldn't be encoded):

```
https://www.example.com/test?firstQueryParam=hot%26cold&secondQueryParam=test
```

To add salt to the injury, Java's `URI` implementation deviates from RFC 3986 and RFC 3987 due to historical / backwards compatibility reasons. Here's an interesting read about some of URI's quirks: [Updating URI support for RFC 3986 and RFC 3987 in the JDK](https://cr.openjdk.org/%7Edfuchs/writeups/updating-uri/).

"Fixing" incorrectly encoded URLs by re-encoding without proper knowledge about the original URL is not a trivial problem. Fixing incorrectly encoded URLs using encoders and decoders full of quirks is even harder. A good enough "best effort" heuristic would be my recommendation.

### A simple best effort solution

So the good news is that I've managed to implement a solution that passes all of the above tests. The solution in question leverages Spring Web [`UriUtils`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriUtils.html) and [`UriComponentsBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriUtils.html). The cherry on the cake is that you may not need [galimatias](https://github.com/smola/galimatias) anymore.

Here's the code:

```java
public class UrlEncoder {

    public Optional<URL> encode(final String link) {
        try {
            final URI validatedURI = reencode(link).parseServerAuthority();
            return Optional.of(validatedURI.toURL());
        } catch (MalformedURLException | URISyntaxException e) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    private URI reencode(String url) { // best effort
        final String decodedUrl = UriUtils.decode(url, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(decodedUrl)
                .encode()
                .build()
                .toUri();;
    }
}
```

Here's the gist of it:

- `reencode` → best attempt to "fix" URL encoding by decoding and re-encoding
- `parseServerAuthority()` → As an alternative to the former `validateUrl(url)` method.

### Double encoding ampersands and other special characters

As previously stated, while the code above passes all tests. It is easy enough to come up with a "broken" test case. E.g., running the URL above through the encoder would result in:

```
https://www.example.com/test?firstQueryParam=hot&cold&secondQueryParam=test
```

This is a perfectly valid URL, but likely not what one would be looking for.

We are now entering dangerous territory, but there are ways to implement a more "opinionated" re-encoding algorithm. E.g. the code bellow deals with ampersands by making sure that `%26` isn't decoded:

```
private final char PERCENT_SIGN = '%';
private final String ENCODED_PERCENT_SIGN = "25";
private final String[] CODES_TO_DOUBLE_ENCODE = new String[]{
        "26" // code for '&'
};

private URI reencode(String url) throws URISyntaxException {
    final String urlWithDoubleEncodedSpecialCharacters = doubleEncodeSpecialCharacters(url);
    final String decodedUrl = UriUtils.decode(urlWithDoubleEncodedSpecialCharacters, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    final String encodedUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(decodedUrl).toUriString();
    final String encodedUrlWithSpecialCharacters = decodeDoubleEncodedSpecialCharacters(encodedUrl);

    return URI.create(encodedUrlWithSpecialCharacters);
}

private String doubleEncodeSpecialCharacters(String url) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(url);
    for (String code : CODES_TO_DOUBLE_ENCODE) {
        final String codeString = PERCENT_SIGN + code;
        int index = sb.indexOf(codeString);
        while (index != -1) {
            sb.insert(index + 1, ENCODED_PERCENT_SIGN);
            index = sb.indexOf(codeString, index + 3);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private String decodeDoubleEncodedSpecialCharacters(String url) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(url);
    for (String code : CODES_TO_DOUBLE_ENCODE) {
        final String codeString = PERCENT_SIGN + ENCODED_PERCENT_SIGN + code;
        int index = sb.indexOf(codeString);
        while (index != -1) {
            sb.delete(index + 2, index + 4);
            index = sb.indexOf(codeString, index + 5);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The solution above can be modified to deal with other escaping sequences (e.g., to deal with all [RFC 3986's Reserved Characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2)), as well as to use more sophisticated heuristics (e.g., to do something different with query parameters, than, say, path parameters).

Nevertheless, as someone that went down this rabbit hole before, I can tell you that once you know that you are dealing with incorrectly encoded URLs outside of your control there simply isn't a perfect solution.

Comment: Woahh, thanks a great deal! This is one of the best answers I got to my question since I'm on this site! I'll award you the 200 points bounty as soon as I can (in 24 hours).

Comment: Thanks for the kind words and for the bounty :).

Comment: I have a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75966165/how-to-replace-the-deprecated-url-constructors-in-java-20 Please can you provide a solution without Spring? Jakarta EE has UriBuilder too: https://javadoc.io/doc/jakarta.platform/jakarta.jakartaee-api/latest/jakarta/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html