# How to replace the deprecated URL constructors in Java 20?

Tags: java, java-20

[All URL constructors are deprecated in Java 20](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html#constructor-deprecation). I replaced `new URL(protocol, host, file)` by `new URI(protocol, host, file, null).toURL()` as I have no query and no fragment but I don't know what to do with the others:

```
/home/gouessej/Documents/programmation/java/workspace/Ardor3D/ardor3d-core/src/main/java/com/ardor3d/util/UrlUtils.java:40: warning: [deprecation] URL(String) in URL has been deprecated
        return new URL(new URL(url), relativeLoc);
                       ^
/home/gouessej/Documents/programmation/java/workspace/Ardor3D/ardor3d-core/src/main/java/com/ardor3d/util/UrlUtils.java:40: warning: [deprecation] URL(URL,String) in URL has been deprecated
        return new URL(new URL(url), relativeLoc);
               ^
/home/gouessej/Documents/programmation/java/workspace/Ardor3D/ardor3d-core/src/main/java/com/ardor3d/util/resource/SimpleResourceLocator.java:94: warning: [deprecation] URL(URL,String) in URL has been deprecated
            final URL rVal = new URL(_baseDir.toURL(), spec);
                             ^
/home/gouessej/Documents/programmation/java/workspace/Ardor3D/ardor3d-audio/src/main/java/com/ardor3d/audio/FilenameURL.java:125: warning: [deprecation] URL(String) in URL has been deprecated
                    url = new URL( filename );
```

Would simply `new URI(filename).toURL()`do the job in the last case?

When I compare the wording in the Java documentation, I understand that an URI scheme means more or less a URL protocol, an URI host is an URL host and an URL file matches with a URI path and an optional URI query. What are the exact equivalent of `new URL(spec)` and `new URL(context, spec)`?

[I prepared some suggested changes](https://jogamp.org/cgit/ardor3d.git/commit/?id=f9690cba75a6bbf352ef9eadf66931a89bc2baa2) but it doesn't work, an IllegalArgumentException is thrown.

Comment: *Would simply new URI(filename).toURL()do the job in the last case?* I would say so, from reading the URI doc.  But it'll only take 5 minutes to try it and see,

Comment: If you want to construct a `file:` scheme URI, then File has a [toURI method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#toURI()).

Comment: The `context,spec` thing can probably be done by `URI.resolve()`?

Comment: Indeed, that very same javadoc states: "The recommended way to manage the encoding and decoding of URLs is to use `URI`, and to convert between these two classes using `toURI()` and `URI.toURL()`."  So the answer to your first question is yes.  The answer to your second question, as teapot pointed out, is `new URI(context).resolve(spec).toURL()`.

Comment: @ArfurNarf It's not so trivial because I can't test all possible special cases depending on file systems. Imagine that it works on a simple case but it doesn't work in another case because a special character isn't escaped. I would like to understand formally how to replace those calls once for all.

Comment: @VGR Actually, your comment clarifies teapot418's suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @VGR I obtain `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute` when I call `new URI(context).resolve(spec).toURL()`.

Comment: Yes, and [the method's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#toURL()) tells you that you will get that exception.  Is there a reason you're using relative URIs?

Comment: @VGR It's a utility of the engine. At the beginning, it was used to work around some bugs or limitations of the URL class. I'll isolate the problem in a tiny unit test.

Comment: If you are trying to make URLs out of relative filenames, I find myself wondering if you’re actually trying to access data built into your application.  If that is the case, you should not be creating URLs yourself at all;  you should use [Class.getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) for that.  You should never rely on relative filenames, since the current directory usually is not something you can control.

Comment: The method is in a utility, it's used both for files on the local filesystem and files from the Internet.

Comment: @VGR Thanks for mentioning the `new URI(context).resolve(spec).toURL()` approach, appreciated. This may resolve my particular issue in another question (which was marked as a duplicate of this). I edited https://stackoverflow.com/a/75968141/227779 to include these details now, please help me verify that I understood you correct.

Comment: @PerLundberg Looks good to me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## tl;dr

- To construct a URL, use [`URI::toURL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#toURL()).
- To construct a relative URL, first create the `URI` using the context URI and then call [`URI::resolve`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#resolve(java.lang.String)) with the URI you wish to make relative.
- To construct a `file:` based URL, (1) call [`Path::toURI`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#toUri()), (2) then `URI::toURL`.

Ex: `URI uri = Paths.get( "/Users/your_user_name/example.txt" ).toUri() ;`

## Details

Understand that:

- [`java.net.URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) is an ancient class, dating from Java 1. That class does not encode or decode any URL components according to the [RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396) escaping mechanism.
- [`java.net.URI`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html) class came later, in Java 4.

Read this note from the Java team, [Oracle: Quality Outreach Heads-up - JDK 20: Deprecate URL Public Constructors](https://inside.java/2023/02/15/quality-heads-up/). To quote:

> JDK 20 will deprecate all public constructors of java.net.URL. … To construct a URL, the [`URI::toURL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#toURL()) alternative should instead be preferred. To construct a `file:` based URL, [`Path::toURI`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#toUri()) should be used prior to `URI::toURL`.

And see the [note on constructor deprecation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html#constructor-deprecation) within the Javadoc  of `URL` class.

See also the issue-tracker page, [JDK-8294241 Deprecate URL public constructors](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8294241).

### Example: File path URI

For working with files in modern Java, use [NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/index.html) features.

The [`Paths`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html) class can produce a [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) object. From there, ask that `Path` to [produce a `URI`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#toUri()).

```java
Path path = Paths.get( "/Users/your_user_name/example.txt" ) ;
URI uri = path.toUri () ;
System.out.println ( "uri = " + uri );
```

> uri = file:///Users/your_user_name/example.txt

Going [the other direction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.net.URI)):

```
Path path = Paths.get( uri ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your elaborated answer. I'll carefully try your suggestions, especially Path.toURI().toURL().

Comment: @gouessej If this Answer solved your problem, please accept it by marking the big check mark. This Question can be used to strike other Questions as duplicates only if an Answer is accepted.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. I still have to isolate a few corner cases.

Comment: e.g.

`var url = URI.create("https://www.example.com").toURL();`

Comment: @Sourabh Thanks for example. That inspired me to add a file-URI example, to match the Question's specifics.