# URL to URI class cast exception

Tags: java, url, uri, httpsurlconnection

I had this code:

```
URL url = new URL(urlStr)
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

And is working correct until I updated to the latest spring/libraries versions. After that it showed me that this constructor new URL(String url) is deprecated in flavor of `URI.toURL()` to construct an instance of `URL`. I rewrite the code to:

```
Path path = Paths.get(urlStr);
URI uri = path.toUri();
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) uri.toURL().openConnection();
```

But it is throwing :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.net.www.protocol.file.fileurlconnection cannot be cast to class javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection (sun.net.www.protocol.file.fileurlconnection and javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

So now i'm searching how to rewrite it to work again.

Comment: It says that the result of `uri.toURL().openConnection()` is a `fileurlconnection`. It doesn't make sense to cast that to a `HttpsURLConnection`, does it?

Comment: Why are you mixing up urls and file paths?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace the deprecated URL constructors in Java 20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75966165/how-to-replace-the-deprecated-url-constructors-in-java-20)

Comment: @Sören no, that does not answer the question. That answer is specifically about file URLs, and the current question is specifically about _avoiding_ making a URL a file URL.

Comment: @k314159 The relevant part is right there in the first line of the answer.

Comment: @Sören that says "use URI::toURL" but it seems that the OP is actually having a problem constructing a URI in the first place, from which he already knows about the `toURL()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javadoc deprecation notice says "See the note on constructor deprecation for more details." And that note says that you can create your URL like this:

```
URL url = URI.create(urlStr).toURL();
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

This works because *every URL is a URI*. Therefore you can pass a URL string to the URI constructor (or to the `create()` convenience method).

Your previous attempt didn't work because `Paths.get(urlStr)` creates a `Path` which is specifically about files (typically on your local filing system), but https doesn't work with local files.